# Linq to SQL Error on updating Foreign key

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I'm a beginner trying to update a  foreign key but it shows this error

> Cannot implicitly convert type '`DynaDNS.DAO.GroupDetail`' to
>   '`long`'

HostDNSDetail
GroupId- FK for Groupdetails
HostDNSId

GroupDetails
GroupId - PK

```
public bool UpdateHostDns(HostDNSDetail HostObj)
{ 
DynaDBDataContext ctx = GetDataContext();

var ExistingDns = (from HostDNS in ctx.HostDNSDetails
             where (HostDNS.HostDNSId) == (HostObj.HostDNSId)
             select HostDNS).FirstOrDefault();

   if (ExistingDns != null)
    {
      ExistingDns.GroupId = ctx.GroupDetails.Single(Existing =>Existing.GroupId ==    HostObj.GroupId); 

    // i m trying to update from the value from "HostObj.GroupId".
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to select the whole object with `GroupDetails.Single`. So, instead of:

```
ExistingDns.GroupId = ctx.GroupDetails.Single(Existing =>Existing.GroupId ==    HostObj.GroupId);
```

you need to do something like:

```
long ExistingDnsId = (from c in ctx.GroupDetails
                      where c.GroupId == HostObj.GroupId
                      select c.GroupId).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: thanks for u r reply , but still it throws the same error "System.Data.Linq.ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
"

Comment: Oh, I see what you are trying to do here...If you are trying to set the ExistingDns.GroupId then try instead: ExistingDns = ctx.GroupDetails.Single(Existing =>Existing.GroupId ==    HostObj.GroupId);    You should be setting the association property instead of the foreign key.

Comment: i found of it i have to set it to the object of the GroupDetails i mean,  ExistingDns.GroupDetail = ctx.GroupDetails.SingleOrDefault(c => c.GroupId == HostObj.GroupId); // where GroupDetail[The object of GroupDetail Table] which is present in the ExistingDns.